# Class does not support Automation or does not support expected interface - when opening any building blocks

Tags: cme, templating, com

Today suddenly in our production environment we got an error while opening any building block of any publication.

The error is:

> Class does not support Automation or does not support expected interface.

If the error was specific to a particular publication I could have narrowed it down but currently the issue is for all the publications.

The issue was resolved by restarting all the services but I really need to know the cause for it.

Event viewer logged the following:

> Unable to get list of SDL Tridion Content Manager items.
> Class does not support Automation or does not support expected interface
>
> Error Code:
> 0x1AE (430)
>
> Call stack:
> Folder.GetListItems

Comment: Could I ask you to tag this question with some more appropriate tags? Version, com+, CME would all be good ones. "building" is really generic

Answer (score 6):

A possible cause of this kind of issue is a memory leak. Sometimes, instead of out-of-memory errors, COM raises automation errors or interface errors. My suggestion is that you set up some perfmon traces on the private bytes of the relevant processes. If this is the problem, you'll see the memory going up to unsustainable levels just before you start to see the errors you report.

Another thing to check is MSDTC. Do you have any unresolved transactions? Having said that, memory issues are a more likely cause.

Answer (score 3):

Confirm the Windows Service 'Tridion Content Manager Service Host' service is running.

I have seen this error in the past for myself.  It's a new Tridion service introduced in Tridion 2011 and is responsible for calling the Core Service from the Tridion GUI.

Comment: It's not Service Host problem. It's related to .Com+ (probably topic starter uses Tridion with version 2011 or less). Reason for this error can be different (just enter to google something like 'Error 430 VB6 .Com+') and I am not sure, that we can find source of the problem, if all is working now.